# Execute an Ansible Playbook periodically

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible Playbook `myPlayBook.yml`. It has two plays and each plays has one or more tasks.

I use the command as follows to run my playbook:

```
ansible-playbook myPlayBook.yml
```

So every thing is OK and my tasks are executed successfully. Now, after the first running I want to run my playbook again from the first play (similar to the first running but automatically). Is there a way to do that?

(I saw that it can be done for a specific task or play with `include` or `include_tasks`, but what about for a playbook?)

Answer (score 2):

> Now, after the first running I want to run my playbook again from the
>   first play (similar to the first running but automatically).

You can form your tasks as role and execute it via [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) from playbook multiple times:

```
- name: 'Include role'
  include_role:
    name: '{{ app_role}}'
```

---

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Create role by the following [path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) `roles/inventory_role` that consist of [one](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) task. From playbook you can execute role just call it multiple times:

```
- name: 'Include role inventory_role'
  include_role:
    name: 'inventory_role'

- name: 'Include role inventory_role'
  include_role:
    name: 'inventory_role'
```

Or you can use something like this:

```
- { role: 'inventory_role' }
- { role: 'inventory_role' }
```

**NOTE**:

> Ansible will only allow a role to execute once, even if defined
>   multiple times, if the parameters defined on the role are not
>   different for each definition.

See for more details: [Role Duplication and Execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-duplication-and-execution).

---

> Execute an Ansible Playbook periodically

`Ansible Tower` have job with scheduled launch type.

Comment: Thanks,  can you take a real example of a `include_role`?